# How do I resize an Azure DevTest Lab VM that uses shared IP configuration

Tags: azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network, azure-devtest-labs

This might be a dreadfully silly question but here goes...

I have a virtual machine in Azure DevTest Labs that was created using shared IP configuration. I now have a requirement to change the size but this fails with the message

> Resizing virtual machine with shared IP configuration is not supported.

Fair enough. I tried disabling shared public IP for the existing lab subnet within the 'Configuration and policies - Virtual networks' blade and retrying the resize opreation. Same error message.

My train of though now is to create a different virtual network without shared public IP, migrate the VM to use that and try and resize that way.

Is there an easier way to do this? Or a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, when the shared IP configuration is enabled at the VM creation time, the public Ip address is disabled with its network interface. You could **enable** the public Ip address then resize your lab VM, this works on my side.

Navigate to DevTest Lab--->my virtual machines(VM name)--->virtualnetwork/subnet--->Device(nic)--->IP configurations--->Public IP address---> enabled.

[image]

Comment: I knew there had to be an easier way and I just could not see it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the instructions at https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/assign-static-public-ip-address-to-azure-vm/ to do this:

> 1. Login to MS Azure portal
> 2. Click “Virtual Machines” from the left menu.
> 3. Select an existing virtual machine from the list.
> 4. Under Settings, click "Networking".
> 5. Click "Network Interface".
> 6. Under Settings, click "IP Configurations".
> 7. Click IP configuration (e.g. ipconfig1).
> 8. Under Public IP address settings, for Public IP address click Enabled.
> 9. Click “IP address”.
> 10. Click “Create New”.
> 11. Under Assignment, select Static.
> 12. Click OK.
> 13. Click Save to save the changes to the network interface.

Answer (score 0):

No need to change PIP configuration, Go -- VM Blade -- Select VM -- Go Size (Under Settings) -- Select the size -- Click Resize